# SQL Server MDF after make my setup

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some questions about `.mdf` SQL Server database files and build setup. I created an application that uses `Database.mdf` to save my CSVS there and problem when I build setup and install program in second PC the `database.mdf` doesn't work correctly.

Does the second PC need to install SQL Server for `*.MDF`?

Any way to put required files in my setup and how?

Comment: **YES!** If you want an application to use a local `.mdf` database file, that PC **must have** SQL Server installed - Express, Web, Standard or Enterprise - just any version, locally installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , after i insttaled SqlLocalDB in second pc (Client PC) my app worked correctly , we dont need whole of SQL Server